# Can't see result of opening Chrome browser with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

The driver version is 2.35
python version 3.6.1
The code gets executed with no errors, but I do not see anything on window.
Here is the python code:

```
def click_red_links():
try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/xampp/htdocs/scout-project-master/chromedriver.exe', service_args=['--whitelisted-ips="x.x.x.x'])
    driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)  # wait 30 seconds.
    print(driver.title)
    driver.quit()
except ValueError:
    print('coudl not open the borwser read: {}'.format(WebDriverException))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
def click_red_links():
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe', service_args=['--whitelisted-ips="x.x.x.x'])
        driver.get('https://www.facebook.com')
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)  # wait 30 seconds.
        print(driver.title)
        #driver.quit()
    except ValueError:
        print('coudl not open the borwser read: {}'.format(WebDriverException))
```

[image]

It works for me with Python 3.6.3, with this webdriver :https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.35/

Does the ChromeDriver Console opens or Chrome opens or nothing happens when you run it?

Comment: Tried, the driver suggested by HaR,  Nothing happens when I run the python script.

Comment: Thank you very much, your screen shot/ verification helped me answer my own question. I was missing  the if __name__ == "__main__"  to execute my function. Thank you very much. It is working now.